# Sql query to assign value to a column having null value from other row based on different scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below real production data scenario and I am trying to get the desired output. I have to populate all the NULL values for the Worker from other rows (next or previous based on data).

**Sample Input**

```
PK  Id  Status      Worker      Created Date
--- --- ----------- ----------- -------------
1   101 Waiting     NULL        1/1/2019 8:00
2   101 Assigned    Jon Doe     1/1/2019 8:10
3   101 Initiated   Jon Doe     1/1/2019 8:15    
4   102 Waiting     NULL        1/1/2019 8:00
5   102 Waiting     NULL        1/1/2019 8:12
6   102 Assigned    Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:15
7   103 Waiting     NULL        1/1/2019 8:00
9   103 Initiated   Jon Doe     1/1/2019 8:15
11  103 Waiting     NULL        1/1/2019 8:17
12  103 Assigned    Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:20
13  103 Assigned    NULL        1/1/2019 8:22
14  103 Initiated   NULL        1/1/2019 8:25
```

**Desired Output**

```
PK  Id  Status      Worker      Created Date
--- --- ----------- ----------- -------------
1   101 Waiting     Jon Doe     1/1/2019 8:00
2   101 Assigned    Jon Doe     1/1/2019 8:10
3   101 Initiated   Jon Doe     1/1/2019 8:15    
4   102 Waiting     Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:00
5   102 Waiting     Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:12
6   102 Assigned    Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:15
7   103 Waiting     Jon Doe     1/1/2019 8:00
9   103 Initiated   Jon Doe     1/1/2019 8:15
11  103 Waiting     Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:17
12  103 Assigned    Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:20
13  103 Assigned    Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:22
14  103 Initiated   Jane Doe    1/1/2019 8:25
```

SQL:

```
select tl.*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tl.[Id],tl.[Created Date]) rnk 
into #temp 
from table tl

select tl.*, 
       case when tl.[Worker] is null t2.[Worker] else tl.[Worker] end as [Worker Updated]
from #temp tl
left join #temp t2 on tl.[Id]=t2.[Id] and tl.rnk=t2.rnk-1
```

I am only able to get the correct result for scenario Id 101 in the Input Data Sample. I am not sure how to handle scenario 102 (two consecutive rows having NULL on Worker column) and 103 (Last 2 rows having NULL on Worker).

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the simplest way is `outer apply`:

```
select t.id, t.status, t2.worker, t.date
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t2
      where t2.worker is not null and t2.id >= t.id
      order by t2.id asc
     ) t2;
```

What you really want is the `IGNORE NULLS` option on `LEAD()`.  However, SQL Server does not support that.

If you want to fill in the most recent values with the *preceding* value, then follow the same logic with another `apply`:

```
select t.id, t.status,
       coalesce(tnext.worker, tprev.worker) as worker, t.date
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t2
      where t2.worker is not null and t2.id >= t.id
      order by t2.id asc
     ) tnext outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t2
      where t2.worker is not null and t2.id <= t.id
      order by t2.id desc
     ) tprev;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but this is again working only for part of my problem. It is not filling the Worker name where there are 2 consecutive NULLs, ex 103 record in my sample.

Comment: @MadZ . . . That is because all the other rows follow the rule "insert the *next* valid worker".  To me, it is unclear that you really want to change this rule for the most recent rows.

Comment: ---the second outer apply worked. thanks much for your help on this

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is `ISNULL()` and `MAX() OVER()` so your query would have something like this :

```
SELECT  
    t1.PK
,   t1.Id
,   t1.Status
,   ISNULL(t1.Worker, MAX(t1.Worker) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) ) Worker
,   t1.CreatedDate
FROM #temp tl
```

ISNULL() will check the value, if is it null will replace it with the secondary value. it's the same the case that you have in your query.

```
MAX(t1.Worker) OVER(PARTITION BY Id)
```

Since the aggregation functions eliminate nulls, we take this advantage and use it with `OVER()` clause to partition the rows by `Id` and get the value that we need using one of the aggregation functions.

Comment: thank you for your reply. this is giving incorrect result and also overwriting the worker name when it is already populated. I only need to fill in the name where it is NULL.